# ¿Por qué si accedo a mi página desde las busquedas de Google aparece insegura a pesar de tener SSL?

Tags: web, ssl, certificado-ssl

Tengo un problema y es que cuando busco mi página web en el buscador de Google y accedo a ella desde ahí aparece como insegura pero al recargarla sí aparece segura con el respectivo certificado SSL, estoy utilizando IIS.

Comment: configuraste tu .htaccess para que te redirija a HTTPS?

Comment: Sí, no htaccess porque ese es de Apache pero sí lo configure con URL Rewrite en IIS

Comment: [IIS Redirect HTTP to HTTPS](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9953/38/iis-redirect-http-to-https) ¿esto resuelve tu pregunta?

Comment: Intenta ingresar a tu sitio desde la versión http para asegurarte que devuelve la redirección. Deberías recibir un redirect 301 viendo la cabecera. Si la respuesta es 200 no esta siendo redireccionado. Asegúrate de configurar correctamente web.config